# Inserting A Feed and Sidebar into an HTML Page

Tags: php, loop, themes, blog

I have a website I've built and the last step is to configure the blog page. My html and css is solid but my php and wordpress development knowledge is almost non-existent.

I don't need a dynamic header or footer. All I need is a blog feed and a sidebar for recent items.

Is it possible to take an existing blog's (using default wordpress 2014 theme) blog feed and recent items widget and insert it into a static html page? So whenever a person updates a blog the static page will be updated as well? Basically I need a user to be able to log into a blog with a default theme and make posts just as they would on a normal wordpress blog but for it to be updated to the static page I've created. Maybe this isn't even the right way to go about doing this.

I know this is kind of a shortcut approach but I don't have much time to do an entire page with wordpress. If anyone has any information or suggestions or can just point me in the right direction I would really really appreciate it. Thanks in advance for anyone who takes the time to read this and comment :)

Comment: You could design a dynamic page yourself that pulls feeds from a WordPress blog via RSS or using XML and the like. There is no shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

The typical definition of static page is plain text file, typed by hand or generated by software either. By definition static pages cannot have back-end powered dynamic functionality.

There are quite a few approaches to integrating WP (or anything really) with static page, typical being:

- convert static page to dynamic

  - completely - turn it into a page of WP site
  - or partially - load WP core in it explicitly and retrieve/output data
- generate and overwrite static page from WP whenever corresponding data is edited
- add JavaScript to static page that retrieves data from WP and injects it into page